# Carousel loop with divs and variable seconds for slide

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm new to jquery. Is all the morning I try to code a carousel with different time for slide, but I can't.
Could you help me?

I have an html with this code, this is only an example, I will output with PHP it.

```
<head>
<style>
    .carousel {
        width: 500px;
        height: 500px;

    }
    [class^="content"] {
        width: 500px;
        height: 500px;
        position: absolute;
    }
    .content1 {
        background-color: #FF0000;
    }
    .content2 {
        background-color: #FFFF00;  
    }
    .content3 {
        background-color: #0000FF;  
    }
    .content4 {
        background-color: #FF66aa;  
    }
</style>
</head>

<div class="carousel">
     <div class="content1"></div>
     <div class="content2"></div>
     <div class="content3"></div>
     <div class="content4"></div>
</div>
```

JQUERY

```
 //Array with the name of the classes (PHP values)
        var div = ["content1", "content2", "content3", "content4"];
    //Array with different time for each slide (PHP values)
        var times = [5000, 10000, 20000, 30000];

        var counter = 0;
        var maxCount = div.length;
```

I tried with something like that (I used an alert but I would like to change the z-index of the single class), but doesn't work:

```
    function timer(sec, counter){
        var ciclo = function(){

            return function() {
                if (counter > 1) {
                    window.setTimeout(timer(times[counter-1], counter-1), times[counter-1]);
                    alert(counter + " " + times[counter-1] );

                }
                else if (counter <= 1) {
                    window.setTimeout(timer(times[maxCount-1], maxCount), times[maxCount-1]);
                    alert(counter + " " + times[counter-1]);

                }
            }

        }

        window.setTimeout(ciclo());


    }

    timer(5000, maxCount);
```

I can see the alert message, but they don't respect the time.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Today I play again with the code and resolved the problem.
I changed little bit the logic; I decided to not change the z-index of single div, but to create only one div and change content inside.

Here my code

HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>

<style>
.carousel {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;

}
[class^="content"] {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    position: absolute;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
.content {
    background-color: #FF0000;
    z-index: 1;
}

</style>
</head>

<body>

<div class="carousel">
    <div class="content"></div>
</div>

[...]
```

JQUERY

```
//Array with the content inside each div (PHP)
        var div = Array();
        div[0] = "<p style=\"font-size:16px;\"> Test 0 </p><p style=\"font-size:36px;\"> Some text here </p>";
        div[1] = "<p style=\"font-size:16px;\"> Test 1 </p><p style=\"font-size:36px;\"> Some other text </p>";
        div[2] = "<p style=\"font-size:16px;\"> Test 2 </p><p style=\"font-size:36px;\"> Here we go </p>";
        div[3] = "<p style=\"font-size:16px;\"> Test 3 </p><p style=\"font-size:36px;\"> Boooom!! </p>";

//Array with different times for each div (PHP)     
        var times = [5000, 10000, 20000, 30000];


var maxCount = div.length - 1;



var funzione = function(time) {

    var timer = function(counter) {
        if (counter === undefined ) { 
            var counter = 0;
        } else if (counter > maxCount) {
            counter = 0
        }
        //alert(counter);
        //$(".content1").empty().append("<p style=\"font-size:36px;\"> " + counter + " </p>");
        $(".content").empty().append(div[counter]);
        $(".content").append(times[counter]);
        counter++;
        window.setTimeout(function(){timer(counter)} , times[counter-1]);
    }


window.setTimeout(function(){timer()} , time);
}

funzione(0);
```

I'm sure this code could become shorter and better, but I hope could help someone there ;)